# Stop bad handler mappings from re-appearing

Tags: asp.net, windows-10, iis-express

I'm on Windows 10 running an ASP.Net web app locally in IIS Express. Initially when I was trying to serve my app on localhost I introduced some bad handler mappings in my IIS Express options for the app. I figured out I didn't have IIS ASP.Net installed as part of IIS and fixed that. Then I removed the bad mappings and everything works. But every time I restart my app in IIS the bad mappings re-appear, and I have to remove them again. How do I permanently delete or remove these bad mappings? Thanks in advance for any replies.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. I added lines to remove the bad handlers in my Web.cong in the system.webServer section ( the Web.config in my projects root folder). The problem was happing everytime I published to the local server. Seems intorducing these lines replaces the Web.config in the app's root folder for the server. Adding these lines seems to fix the problem. Here's the lines I added:

```
<handlers>
    <remove name="Start Module" />
    <remove name="Start" />
</handlers>
```